# unable to display emoji on web browser

Tags: php, ios, emoji

I am working on a webapp project related to SMS that already has a well working iOS app.
Most of the messages contain Emoji and work well on the mobile app. But even after a lot of tries, I am unable to open (or parse) it for web browser viewing. It seems to be an encoding related issue - but I am unable to figure out the solution.

Following image describes the whole problem well ('detail' field stores the messages & data is being sent through XML in utf-8 encoding via PHP.).

[image: 'detail' field stores the messages & data is being sent through XML in utf-8 encoding via PHP.]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726423/how-to-insert-emoji-utf8-4-byte-characters-into-mysql-5-5).

Comment: [Here](http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/) is a PHP lib, that claims to be able to handle iOS emojis.

Comment: @Anticom Input data for this PHP lib is hexadecimal `like 0x2601 - Value of Cloud ` And my data is `â˜ ï¸` My Question is How should i convert `â˜ ï¸` value to `0x2601`